# want to make color grid like textEdit for mac osx application

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion, color-picker

i want to make color picker like attached image.[image]

Please help me out what should i have to use or which controller needed?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

IMO the best choice for color selection is using system pickers like `NSColorWell` or (on toolbar) `NSToolbarItem` with identfier = `NSToolbarShowColorsItemIdentfier`